# How to display labels on bubble chart, Numbers (v3.2)

Tags: numbers

I want to display the label of each bubble on a bubble chart in numbers. How do you do this? I want either a truncated "description" or the 3-digit NAICS to be the label of the bubble.

Here's an example of what I'd like (Google Docs).
[image]

Here's my dataset in Numbers.
[image]

I'd appreciate any help!